# Quesions on Facebook filters

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm trying to filter using the following code adding the field Installed=true
but it's not working for me ... No errors, just throwing all friends without any filters

```
$user_friends = $fb->api('/me', array('fields' => 'friends' ) );
print_r($user_friends);
$friend_array = $user_friends['friends']['data'];
foreach ( $friend_array as $current ) {
   echo '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'.$current['id'].'/picture" />';
   echo '<br />';
}
```

I'm using this document
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Comment: No errors, just throwing all friends without any filters :(, sorry about not explaining that will add it on here

Comment: Not sure why you want to filter... Can you elaborate? The "installed" field determines "Is the app making the request installed?" as described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/#fields

Comment: It's an initial filter to show friends having the same app installed, it can be used to filter by gender and something else like age group later as well ;)

Comment: You cannot "filter" with the Graph API. You'll have to use FQL queries instead. But you can apply application-based "filters" on the results of the Graph API calls...

Comment: Resolve it already thanks for your help Tobi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the results in your application to get only those of your freinds who installed your app:

```
$user_friends = $fb->api('/me/friends', array('fields' => 'id,installed' ) );
print_r($user_friends);
$friend_array = $user_friends['friends']['data'];
foreach ( $friend_array as $current ) {
    if (array_key_exists('installed', $current)) {
       echo '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'.$current['id'].'/picture" />';
       echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help!, I'm getting an error :(, Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/website.com/fb/index.php on line 123; Data is coming out like: Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 103234 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 121376 ) Any clues?

Comment: Looks like Facebook only returns the "installed" field when the User actually installed the application. See my updated answer.